# unable to install django-allauth

Tags: python, django

When trying to install django-all auth with pip i get this error:

```
Collecting django-allauth
  Using cached django-allauth-0.51.0.tar.gz (709 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
          from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
          __import__(extant)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
          collections.MutableMapping.register(ParseResults)
      AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and using python3.10.

I've tried updating pip. installing setuptools, build-essential, g++. With no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you need to downgrade python version to 3.7 or 3.8.

Comment: I switched pip to python3.7 and it seemed to work thanks :D